# $S = \{1,2,...,2005\}$, $A = \{a_{1}, ..., a_{k}\} \subset S$ with $a_{i}+a_{j}$ not multiple of 125. What is $\max(k)$?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

$S = \{1,2,...,2005\}$, $A = \{a_{1}, ..., a_{k}\} \subset S$ with $a_{i}+a_{j}$ not multiple of 125 whenever $a_{i} \ne a_{j}$. What is $max(k)$?

---

**Attempt:**

After exploring, I found that

- We can put only one multiple of 125 among $125,...,2000$ to $A$.
- I found that for easier problem: if $S=\{1,2,...,250\}$, then 
  $$ A = \underbrace{\{1,2,...,62 \}}_{S_{1}} \cup \underbrace{\{126, 127, ..., 187\}}_{S_{2}} \cup \{c\} $$
  where $c$ is any one of 125 or 250, satisfies the demanding rule. $|A|=62+62+1$.
- Because notice for any $x,y \in S_{2}$ and any $x_{1} \in S_{1}$, then $250 <x+y < 375$, and $125 <x_{1}+x< 250$. And for any $x,y \in S_{1}$, $x+y <125$.
- Next, let $B = S - A = (\{63,...,125\} \cup \{188,...,250\})- \{c\}$. $|B|=125$. Notice that for any $b \in B$ there is a partner $a \in A$ such that $a+b=125$ (or $250$).
- For this easier problem, it will be proven that $max(k)=125$. Assume there is $C$ satisfying rule such that $|C|=126$. Then at least one element of $C$ must be from $B$. Let $C = B' \cup A'$ with $B' \subset B$ and $A' \subset A$. If $|B'|=k$ and $|A'|=126-k$ with $1 \le k \ge 125 $, then it is easy to see there will be contradiction for any value of $k$. So $|C|=126$ is impossible, and this implies $|C|>126$ is also impossible.

Now back to original problem: 
Let 
$$S_{1} = \{1,2,...,62\} $$
$$S_{2} = \{125+1,...,125+62\} $$
$$S_{3} = \{2(125)+1, ..., 2(125)+62\}$$
$$...$$
$$S_{16} = \{15(125)+1, .., 15(125) + 62\}$$
$$S_{17} = \{16(125)+1, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005\}$$

We have these facts:

- For $S_{1}$ any 2-combination will have sum less than 125. For $i > 1$, for any $x,y \in S_{i}$ then $ (i)125 < x+y < (i+1)125$.
- Since $S_{i} = \{i(125) + 1, ..., i(125) + 62\}$, then for any $x_{i} \in S_{i}$, and $x_{j} \in S_{j}$, we have 
  $$ (i+j)125 < x_{i} + x_{j} < (i+j)125 + 124 < (i+j+1)125 $$

So $A = S_{1} \cup S_{2} ... \cup S_{17} \cup \{c\} $
where $c$ is can be any number from $\{125,...,2000\}$ satisfy the rule. $|A| = 62(16) + 5 + 1 = 998$.

We will show that $max(k) = 998$. Let $B = S - A$, notice that for any $b \in B$ there exist an $a \in A$ such that $a+b$ is multiple of 125. $|B| = 1007$.

If there exist $C$ satisfying the rule, with $|C|=999$, then it at least has one element from $B$.

Let $C = B' \cup A'$ with $B' \subset B$, $A' \subset A$. If $B' = k$, $A' = 999-k$, with $1 \le k \le 999$.

How to finish the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than talk about ranges of numbers, talk about residues $\bmod 125$.  As you note, you can have only one number equivalent to $0 \bmod 125$.  You cannot have both a number equivalent to $1 \bmod 125$ and $124 \bmod 125$.  There are more numbers equivalent to $1$ than to $124$, so take all the ones equivalent to $1$.  Make the same argument for all the other pairs of residues $(n, 125-n)$.  We get $1$ number equivalent to $0$, $17$ equivalent to each of $1-5$, and $16$ equivalent to $6-62$ for a total of $998$